Looking for query to extract an email address from a column
Using a query, I want to generate the Result table from the Data table.



Data




This address, abc123@email.net, is great


xyz13@email.com is a better email address


The best address is qrz123@email.org






Result




abc123@email.net


xyz13@email.com


qrz123@email.org



I've seen regexextract to get the email address (as in the following line), but I would like to include that or some code like it within the query and am not sure how to do it.
=iferror(Regexextract(C3,"[A-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-z0-9.-]+\.[A-z]{2,4}"),"")

When I use the function above, I do get the email addresses of rows 1 and 2 from the Data table, but not the email address from row 3.
I've started with
=query(data,"SELECT *",1)

to repeat the cells in the Data table and am trying to substitute code for the *, but am getting errors. For example, I tried
=query(data,"SELECT Regexextract(A,"[A-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-z0-9.-]+\.[A-z]{2,4}")",1)

which shows an error. I prefer to use the query function so that I don't have to copy the Regexextract function down a column.

QUERY is not designed to have a formula autopopulate without dragging it down. You should use ARRAYFORMULA for this.
Assuming the formula you have is correct, the formula would be:
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A4,"[A-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-z0-9.-]+\.[A-z]{2,4}")))


Replace A2:A4 with your range.

Thanks. The arrayformula worked perfectly. So, I assume that I'll have to copy that formula for all rows that I want to extract the email addresses. My data includes hundreds of rows.
